301 Redirections (setup off-site)
On my Shopify store, I have 3-4k thousand URLs for my product pages that contain obsolete parameters (in URL). The product pages still exist, but the parameters no longer correspond to anything.
URL: /products/feuillages?pr_prod_strat=collection_fallback&pr_rec_id=a890f7df9&pr_rec_pid=8855045112140&pr_ref_pid=8855047733580&pr_seq=uniform
And URL: /products/feuillages?pr_prod_strat=collection_fallback&pr_rec_id=12029f4fb&pr_rec_pid=8855045112140&pr_ref_pid=8854478881100&pr_seq=uniform
Both correspond to the same product page, but beforehand this page had two distinct contents depending on the parameters. So duplicate content wasn't a problem.
Today, these parameters no longer correspond to anything and end up on the same product page with the same content. Posing a duplicate content problem…
Since these URLs with parameters are indexed and ranked in Google, I’d like to make Google understand that these URLs no longer exist and have been moved by making 301s from URLs with parameters to the “naked” version of the URL, without parameters.
Shopify doesn’t allow redirects from URLs with parameters. Nor does it allow redirection from Live Pages to Live Pages, only from 404 to Live Pages. I don't have access to my .htaccess either. PHP and many other languages cannot be injected into Shopify, only JavaScript (which does not allow 301s but only window.location.href), Liquid and CSS (both of which do not allow redirects). Since it’s my host, I’m stuck for all on-site redirection. All I can do is work on off-site (off my web host) redirects.
So I thought of operating redirects on DNS.
But all those I've found - EasyRedir, Cloudflare, Redirhub - only offer between 10 and 25 redirects... (based on my understanding) That's a long way from the 3-4k I need!
Does anyone know of a service capable of performing DNS redirects in this number and from URLs containing parameters to naked URLs of the same domain name?
Or have an idea other than redirects from DNS?
In my view, there are three solutions:

Create 4k redirects from my 4k URLs with parameters to the 220 corresponding pages (without URL parameters). From example.com/page?123 and/or example.com/page?ABC to example.com/page
Create 220 page rules for my 220 destination pages. URL pattern: example.com/page* (this * will take into account any string of parameters) to "example.com/page"
Create 1 page rule per Regex. Source URL: *?pr_prod=* Destination URL: *

I would prefer solution 1, but otherwise solutions 2 and 3 are feasible and equal in my order of preference.
